create partitioned table via bigquery query
I have an existing table that I wish to filter then add a partition.  For a minimal example, consider the table toy below:
#The base table
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE tmp.toy AS
(
  SELECT 1 as part_col, 1 as col2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 1 as part_col, 2 as col2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 as part_col, 3 as col2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 as part_col, 4 as col2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 as part_col, 5 as col2 
)

How can I run a query on this table to partition toy by part_col?

Things I have tried

per the docs, I tried the following:

CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE tmp.part_example
PARTITION BY part_col
AS
(
  SELECT * 
  FROM tmp.toy
  WHERE col2 < 5
)
;

This yielded the following error:
Query error: PARTITION BY expression must be DATE(<timestamp_column>), DATE(<datetime_column>), DATETIME_TRUNC(<datetime_column>, DAY/HOUR/MONTH/YEAR), a DATE column, TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(<timestamp_column>, DAY/HOUR/MONTH/YEAR), DATE_TRUNC(<date_column>, MONTH/YEAR), or RANGE_BUCKET(<int64_column>, GENERATE_ARRAY(<int64_value>, <int64_value>[, <int64_value>])) at [11:1]

In light of this error I changed the second line to as follows:
PARTITION BY INT64(part_col).  This only yielded additional errors.


Hi @Ottpocket, as mentioned in the error PARTITION BY expression must be a RANGE_BUCKET to be able to generate the expected results as per your base table example. Try creating a partition table as per the integer-range partition example documentation.

Looks like a question that would be more at home on [DBA.se]

Hi @Ottpocket, If my answer addressed your question, do consider accepting and upvoting it as per Stack Overflow guidelines, helping more Stack contributors with their research. If not, let me know so that I can improve my answer.

As per my comment mentioned earlier, to overcome the error PARTITION BY expression must be a RANGE_BUCKET to be able to generate the expected results as per your base table example. Following range partition example docmuentation can be checked for your reference.
The query is as follows after making the changes:


#The base table

CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE tmp.toy AS
(
SELECT 1 as part_col, 1 as col2 UNION ALL
SELECT 1 as part_col, 2 as col2 UNION ALL
SELECT 2 as part_col, 3 as col2 UNION ALL
SELECT 2 as part_col, 4 as col2 UNION ALL
SELECT 2 as part_col, 5 as col2

)





CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE tmp.part_example
PARTITION BY RANGE_BUCKET(part_col, GENERATE_ARRAY(0, 10, 1))
AS
(
SELECT *
FROM tmp.toy
WHERE col2 < 5
)
;




As per @Nithish's comment, the RANGE_BUCKET is the trick.  Change the second line to
PARTITION BY RANGE_BUCKET(part_col, GENERATE_ARRAY(0, 10, 1))

and you have partitioned the table
